# Fragment : Failure delivering result

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, onactivityresult

I have three fragments.
Fragment1: A list fragment displaying a list of data, 
Fragment2: displaying a list of data sources
Fragment3: displays the details of a data source.

To switch to a new display of data in Fragment1, I use startActivityForResult which brings up Fragment2, I choose a new source of data by clicking, it returns a result with an intent that contains a string and this works successfully, Fragment1 opens the new data source and displays it.

However, if I go from fragment1 to fragment2 and before selecting a new data source, I navigate to fragment3 to look at the details of the data source, then navigate back to fragment2, when fragment2 returns its result, I get the following error:

```
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409): Process: aston.cs3040.rssitemfragment, PID: 1409
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=0, data=null} to activity {aston.cs3040.rssitemfragment/aston.cs3040.rssfeedfragment.RssListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3346)
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3389)
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1445)
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409):     at aston.cs3040.rssfeedfragment.RssListFragment.onActivityResult(RssListFragment.java:71)
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:166)
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5435)
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3342)
01-28 10:29:38.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1409):     ... 11 more
```

Here is my code:

For moving between Fragment1 and Fragment2 (a fragment inside a class called RssFeedManagerActivity) I have in Fragment1:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_add_feed:
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                RssFeedManagerActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, MANAGE_FEED);
        // see end of chapter 10 for how to wire this up
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MANAGE_FEED  && data != null) {
        // handle the result
        String link = data.getStringExtra("URL"); // this is RssListFragment.java:71 
        Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "Load: " + link);
        loadFeed(link);
    }
}
```

In Fragment2 I have the following code to return to Fragment1

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("URL", command[1]);
Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "finish and load..." + command[1]);
// load the feed finish this fragment
getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
getActivity().finish();
```

If I want to go from Fragment2 to Fragment3 the code is:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    FeedDetails details = ((FeedMgrListAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position); // (FeedDetails) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "Clicked " + details.getTitle());
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FeedDetailsFormActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("POSITION", position);
    Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "Click tag: " + ((String)v.getTag()));
    if (position == TheNews.getInstance().getFeeds().size()-1) {
        TheNews.getInstance().getFeeds().add(position, new FeedDetails("http://","category", "Feed Title"));
    }   
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And from Fragment3 back to Fragment2 I have:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        if (NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity()) != null) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
        }
        return true;
```

Why does Fragment1 to Fragment2 and Back correctly work but Fragment1 to Fragment2 to Fragment3 and back to 1 again not work?  The Log message printed out when returning from Fragment2 to Fragment1 indicates that the intent has the correct string added in its extras.
My if statement in onActivityResult checks that data is not equal to null and yet on the next line there seems to be a null pointer exception.

Here is the full code:

Fragment1 is this:

```
public class RssListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private TheNews theNews;
    public static final int MANAGE_FEED = 1;
    public boolean reportingBack=false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        theNews = TheNews.getInstance();
        this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.feed_list_mgr, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_add_feed:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                    RssFeedManagerActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, MANAGE_FEED);
            // see end of chapter 10 for how to wire this up
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == MANAGE_FEED  && data != null) {
            // handle the result
            String link = data.getStringExtra("URL");
            Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "Load: " + link);
            /* TheNews.getTheNews(getActivity(), this).*/ loadFeed(link);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        RssItem item = (RssItem) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
        CheckBox c = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.read_or_not);
        Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG,
                "Click id " + id + " title " + item.getTitle()
                        + " checkbox is " + (c.isChecked() ? "" : " not ")
                        + "checked");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RssItemPagerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("POSITION", position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (theNews == null) {
            Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "OnResume: Get the news");
            // create the news singleton and wait for callback
            theNews = TheNews.getTheNews(getActivity(), this);
            loadFeed(theNews.getFeeds().get(0).getUri());
        } else {
            // singleton previously constructed so we have the data already
            if (!reportingBack) {
                Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "Report Back onResume ");
                if (getListAdapter() == null) {
                    Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "Creating list adapter");
                    setListAdapter(new RssItemListAdapter(this.getActivity(), theNews.getFeed().getItems()));
                }
                //((RssItemListAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                //reportBack(theNews.getFeed());
            } else {
                reportingBack = false;
                Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "OnResume: I reported back");
                //((RssItemListAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                //Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "Report Back Invalidate View ");
                //this.getView().invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //reportingBack = false;
    }

    public void reportBack(RssFeed completeFeed) {
        reportingBack = true;
        //Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "Report Back: " + completeFeed);
        if (completeFeed != null) {
            // if (getListAdapter() == null) {
                Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "Creating list adapter");
                setListAdapter(new RssItemListAdapter(this.getActivity(), completeFeed.getItems()));
                /* 
            } else {
                Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "Finished AsyncTask: list changed");
                this.getView().invalidate();
                ((RssItemListAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                // this.getView().invalidate();
            }
            */
        } else {
            // No Network? No Feed?
            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(),
                    "Could not connect to feed.  Is your network connected?",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }

    private class RssItemListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RssItem> {

        public RssItemListAdapter(Activity a, List<RssItem> items) {
            super(a, 0, items);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.list_layout_rss_item, null);
            }
            RssItem item = theNews.getItem(position);
            Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "Get View in List Adapter, ITEM: "
                    + item.getTitle());
            TextView titleTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rss_item_titleTextView);
            titleTextView.setText(item.getTitle());
            TextView dateTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rss_item_date);
            dateTextView.setText(item.getDate());
            CheckBox readCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.read_or_not);
            readCheckBox.setChecked(item.isRead());
            return convertView;
        }
    }
    private class RssReadFeed extends AsyncTask<String, Void, RssFeed> {
        //private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(mAppContext);

        @Override
        protected RssFeed doInBackground(String... urls) {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SaxRssHandler handler = new SaxRssHandler();
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
                Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "loading new feed... " + url);
                InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "Now parse the input");
                parser.parse(is, handler);
                Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "Parsing done");

                return handler.getFeed();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //this.dialog.setMessage("Processing..."); 
            //this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(RssFeed completeFeed) {
            // may report back null if is wasn't possible to download the data
            //theFeed = completeFeed;
            theNews.setFeed(completeFeed);
            Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "Updated new feed with " + completeFeed.getItems().size() + " items");
            reportBack(completeFeed);
            //this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public void loadFeed(String uri) {
        String[] urlToRssFeed = { uri };
        RssReadFeed process = new RssReadFeed();
        process.execute(urlToRssFeed);
    }

}
```

Fragment2 is:

```
public class RssFeedManagerFragment extends ListFragment implements OnClickListener {

    private TheNews theNews;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        theNews = TheNews.getInstance();
        Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "Setting list adapter for a list of length "
                + theNews.getFeeds().size());
        FeedMgrListAdapter adapter = new FeedMgrListAdapter(theNews.getFeeds(), this);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
        this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.feed_mgr_title);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity()) != null) {
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        FeedDetails details = ((FeedMgrListAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position); // (FeedDetails) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "Clicked " + details.getTitle());
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FeedDetailsFormActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("POSITION", position);
        Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "Click tag: " + ((String)v.getTag()));
        if (position == TheNews.getInstance().getFeeds().size()-1) {
            TheNews.getInstance().getFeeds().add(position, new FeedDetails("http://","category", "Feed Title"));
        }

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (getListAdapter() != null) {
            FeedMgrListAdapter arrayAdapter = (FeedMgrListAdapter) getListAdapter();
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private class FeedMgrListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FeedDetails> {
        private List<FeedDetails> items;
        private RssFeedManagerFragment fragment;

        public FeedMgrListAdapter(List<FeedDetails> items, RssFeedManagerFragment fragment) {
            super(getActivity(), 0, items);
            this.items = items;
            this.fragment = fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView titleTextView = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        // R.layout.normal_list_item, null);
                        R.layout.feed_list_layout, null);
            }
            titleTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.title_text_view);
            FeedDetails item = items.get(position);
            if (position == items.size() - 1) {
                titleTextView.setTextColor(0xffcccccc);
                ((ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.load_button)).setClickable(false);
                ((ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button)).setClickable(false);
            } else {
                titleTextView.setTextColor(0xff0000ff);
                ((ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.load_button)).setTag("Load!" + items.get(position).getUri());
                ((ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.load_button)).setOnClickListener(fragment);
                ((ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button)).setTag("Delete!" + position);
                ((ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button)).setOnClickListener(fragment);
            }
            Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "Pos " + position + " title: " + item.getTitle());
            titleTextView.setText(item.getTitle());
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "Click tag: " + ((String)v.getTag()));
        String[] command = ((String)v.getTag()).split("!");
        if (command.length == 2) {
            if (command[0].equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
                TheNews.getInstance().deleteFeed(Integer.parseInt(command[1]));
                ((FeedMgrListAdapter)this.getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            if (command[0].equalsIgnoreCase("load")) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra("URL", command[1]);
                Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG, "finish and load..." + command[1]);
                // load the feed finish this fragment
                //theNews.getFeed().clear();
                getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Fragment3 is:

```
public class FeedDetailsFormFragment extends Fragment {
    private FeedDetails feed;
    private static final String DIALOG_DATE = "date";
    private static final int REQUEST_DATE = 0;
    private Button dateButton;

    public FeedDetailsFormFragment() {
        super();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int position = getArguments().getInt("POSITION");
        feed = TheNews.getInstance().getFeeds().get(position);
        this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.new_feed_title);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity()) != null) {
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public static FeedDetailsFormFragment newInstance(int position) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("POSITION", position);
        FeedDetailsFormFragment fragment = new FeedDetailsFormFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_details_form, parent, false);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.new_feed_title);
        EditText title = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.feedTitle);
        title.setText(feed.getTitle());
        title.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                feed.setTitle(s.toString());

            }
        });
        EditText uri = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.feedUri);
        uri.setText(feed.getUri());
        uri.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                feed.setUri(s.toString());

            }
        });

        EditText cat = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.feedCategory);
        cat.setText(feed.getCategory());
        cat.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                feed.setCategory(s.toString());

            }
        });
        dateButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.feedDate);
        updateDate();
        dateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                DatePickerFragment dialog = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(feed
                        .getDate());
                dialog.setTargetFragment(FeedDetailsFormFragment.this,
                        REQUEST_DATE);
                dialog.show(fm, DIALOG_DATE);
            }

        });
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_DATE) {
            Date date = (Date) data
                    .getSerializableExtra(DatePickerFragment.EXTRA_DATE);
            Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG,
                    "Setting date of feed " + date.toString());
            feed.setDate(date);
            updateDate();
        }
    }

    private void updateDate() {
        Log.i(RssItemActivity.TAG,
                "Setting date button " + feed.getDateAsString());
        dateButton.setText(feed.getDateAsString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the complete code for the fragments .There are a lot of things not clear form the questin

Comment: I have added the full code for each of the three fragments.

Comment: Part of the answer is that I get Activity.Result_Canceled sometimes.  When I check for that I can catch the error.  I have no idea why sometimes the result is cancelled.